# Mips selection sort not working correctly?

Tags: sorting, assembly, selection, mips

I have been looking at this for a long time, and i can not figure out what is not working correctly. Basically what I need to do is take an array of integers, and sort them using selection sort, I have done this is java and c, so I know how it works, but assembly is just not working right.

Here is my code for it in assembly:

```
    li $t0, 0  #$t0 is used as i
    addi $t1, $t0, 1
    li $t2, 0   #t2 is used as j
    sll $t5, $t1, 2

ILoop:

    JLoop:
        lw $t3, array($t2)
        lw $t4, array($t5)
        ble $t3, $t4, Jelse
        sw $t3, temp
        sw $t4, array($t2)
        lw $t4, temp
        sw $t4, array($t5)

    Jelse:
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        sll $t5, $t1, 2
        blt $t1, 4, JLoop

Ielse:          
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    sll $t2, $t0, 2
    blt $t0, 3, ILoop
```

example of output:

The array before being sorted:

25 17 31 13 2

The array after being sorted:

13 2 0 17 25

What am I missing?? or what did I misplace please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might just be as simple as not looping far enough (your inner loop loops while `j<len-1`, and the outer one while `i<len-2`). You could probably find out by stepping through the code in SPIM.
Here's a working implementation for your reference:

```
# Sorts in ascending order

    li $t0, 0               #$t0 is used as i

ILoop:
    sll $t2,$t0,2           # pos = i (scaled for word elements)
    addiu $t5,$t2,4         # j = i+1 (scaled for word elements)

JLoop:
    lw $t3, array($t2)      # array[pos]
    lw $t4, array($t5)      # array[j]
    ble $t3, $t4, JElse
    move $t2,$t5            # pos = j
JElse:
    addiu $t5,$t5,4
    blt $t5,20,JLoop        # 20 = array_length * sizeof(word)

    # if (pos != i) swap(array[pos], array[i])
    sll $t1,$t0,2
    beq $t2,$t1,SkipSwap    # skip if pos==i
    lw $t3, array($t2)      # $t3 = array[pos]
    lw $t4, array($t1)      # $t4 = array[i]
    sw $t4, array($t2)      # array[pos] = array[i]      
    sw $t3, array($t1)      # array[i] = array[pos]     
SkipSwap:

    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    blt $t0, 4, ILoop       # run ILoop while i<array_length-1
```

Comment: Did you mean selection sort? Its suppose to be selection sort.. haha

Comment: Oops, must've been too early in the morning. I've updated my answer.